# How to functionally increase number in array if previous one is lower

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have array of numbers that decreases, but I want it never to decrease:

`const numbers =[0,1,2,3,4,5,1, 2];`

Desired result is:

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]`

I know how to achieve it with for loop:

```
for (let index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
    const element = numbers[index];
    if (index > 0) {
      const prevEl = numbers[index - 1];
      if (element < prevEl) {
        numbers[index] = prevEl;
      }
    }
  }
```

But when using map

```
numbers.map((item, index) => {
    const prevEl = numbers[index - 1];
    if (item < prevEl) {
        return prevEl;
      }
    return item;
})
```

```js
const numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,1, 2];

const result = numbers.map((item, index) => {
    const prevEl = numbers[index - 1];
    if (item < prevEl) {
        return prevEl;
      }
    return item;
});

console.log(result); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2]
```

I get this instead: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2]`

What would be the functional way to achieve this?

Comment: when using map I am getting this `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]`

Comment: You miss to handle the case when `index === 0`in the map.

Comment: Your code won't work for `[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: Thank you @Nick, I updated the question to match this case.
Map doesn't work as expected switched to solution you proposed with Math.max. Thanks!

Comment: math.max is something additional, the actual thing what you were missing is map function can return the updated list it does not modify the original list as you expected. Also you are not supposed to alter the list while its being iterated by map function so you could simply update ur code as

`let updated_array = numbers.map((item, index) => {if (index > 0) {const prevEl = numbers[index - 1];if (item < prevEl) {return prevEl;}}return item;});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Math.max` between the current and the preceding entries in the list:

```js
const numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,1, 2];

result = numbers.map((v, i, a) => Math.max(v, ...a.slice(0, i)))
console.log(result)
```

Note that you could/should just use `Math.max(...a.slice(0, i+1))` since `v` is `a[i]`, I wrote it the way I did for clarity as to what the code is doing.